# Add attributes and innerHTML of AngularJS on the fly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okay, I'm very new to angular and I read already about it from different sources to understand it well enough,
apparently I'm still struggling to make it work in some way,

I already had the simple htmlpage:

```
<html>
<body ng-app>
   <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

then, after I request the data to the server, I create something like this:

```
function updateView($scope){
   $scope.test="Success";
}

window.onload=function(){
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var add = document.createElement("div");
    add.innerHTML = "{{test}}";
    content.appendChild(add);
    content.setAttribute("ng-controller", "updateView");
};
```

and what I got as a result was an html page with a text : {{test}}

so I assume that it's not working,

I know that this might have something to do with creating the content and ng-controller on the fly, and this can be accomplished in more basic way as many tutorial does, but I need the method I specified (add attribute and content(test) on the fly) because I will display something I request from the server which can have varied amount of data, say if it has 3 data in an array form, the "var add=document.createElement("div")" will be called 3 times and I will need to attach the attribute ng-controller to each of them

Is there a work around that I haven't known yet?

Comment: You should probably be using `ng-repeat` to loop over the data returned from your server

Comment: tried, the problem was in the adding the "{{}}" to the innerHTML, it is not linking

Comment: what data structure do you get back from the server? You shouldn't be doing anything angular related in the onload function

Comment: @jonnyynnoj it is array of objects, I used that array as the object needed in ng-repeat, to no avail

Comment: like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/nzutUMnkUaqRYLvoXpWs?p=preview

Comment: @jonnyynnoj yes. more or less, but that is not the problem, but yes, I need to do it in onload

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish what you are trying to do in Angular you will need to use the $compile service, which you can read more about [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile).  This allows you to append html to the dom and link it to your scope variables.

For your specific example you could get the $compile service in the window.onload method like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    angular.element("body").injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        var add = document.createElement("div");
        add.innerHTML = "{{test}}";
        content.appendChild(add);
        content.setAttribute("ng-controller", "updateView");
        $compile(template.contents())(scope);
    });
};
```

Comment: The link may theoretically answer the question, but [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.